# Is the lack of an IP address in the AN field of an SSL certificate a vulnerability?

Tags: certificates

When accessing a HTTPS site by IP address, if the IP address is not in the alternate names field, the browser will throw an error about the certificate not matching.

Would this be considered a low risk vulnerability? If an attacker can force the use of an IP address, then surely the certificate is no longer of any value at this point (unless installed on a client machine)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would this be considered a low risk vulnerability?

Yes.

> If an attacker can force the use of an IP address, then surely the
> certificate is no longer of any value at this point (unless installed
> on a client machine)?

I'm not quite sure I understand the question. Even if an IP address is forced by an attacker and the IP address is not defined as a SAN, the traffic will still be encrypted.

However, keep in mind that [RFC 6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125#section-1.7.2) recommends against strictly using an IP address as the defined name:

> Some certification authorities issue server certificates based on
> IP addresses, but preliminary evidence indicates that such
> certificates are a very small percentage (less than 1%) of issued
> certificates.  Furthermore, IP addresses are not necessarily
> reliable identifiers for application services because of the
> existence of private internets [PRIVATE], host mobility, multiple
> interfaces on a given host, Network Address Translators (NATs)
> resulting in different addresses for a host from different
> locations on the network, the practice of grouping many hosts
> together behind a single IP address, etc.  Most fundamentally,
> most users find DNS domain names much easier to work with than IP
> addresses, which is why the domain name system was designed in the
> first place.  We prefer to define best practices for the much more
> common use case and not to complicate the rules in this
> specification.

**UPDATE:**

It seems that Symantec, along with several other CA's will no longer issue certificates without a valid FQDN.

> For this reason, the leading Certification Authorities, including Symantec, that make up the Certification Authority/Browser Forum (CA/B Forum) have decided to cease issuing certificates without a Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN).

Please reference: http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/important-changes-ssl-certificates-intranets-what-you-need-know

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To clarify my second point, imagine a scenario where an attacker has sabotaged or taken down DNS, so a user has to connect via IP address (a savvy enough user to know how to do so, but not knowledgeable on security). Now when the user connects via IP and the cert isn't valid, isn't it trivial to MitM at this stage?

Comment: @SonnyOrdell No, it's not trivial to MitM. Because the user should give up and go away at this point. If you can't access a site using a hostname that its certificate is valid for, you shouldn't be accessing it at all. The fix for your "problem" is simple; never use IP addresses for HTTPS connections, _even if that's the only way you can connect_.

Comment: In that very specific scenario, yes. But I would hope if the user is savvy enough to access the site by IP, I would hope they would be savvy enough to read the warning for the reason "why" the certificate was untrusted when accessing the site by IP. Was it because there was a name mismatch? Was it because the certificate chain was broken? Was it because the CA was untrusted? The latter two would indicate a possible MitM attempt.

Comment: @MikeScott, your input seem to ignore real world use cases, or how real users behave. Or both.

Comment: One thing to note, if the users have a propensity to click past certificate warnings then the attacker doesn't have to take the DNS down, or force a connection by IP. The attacker can spoof any secured site with a MitM and the user would click passed the warning prompts.

Comment: @k1DBLITZ I know many network people who will know to try by IP address, but won't think twice about getting an SSL error if they only get the error when accessing by IP, because there certs don't tend to have IPs in the AN field. It seems to be a pretty common scenario.

Comment: @SonnyOrdell There is _no_ real-world use case for accessing a TLS/SSL site by IP address, except possibly security testing.

Comment: @MikeScott It happens regularly.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the certificate is of value. If the attacker can "force the use of an IP address" then as you've stated the user will be notified that there is something wrong and they should not proceed.

Comment: Right, so the user won't know if they can accept the certificate or not - which makes it kind of useless in that situation, does it not?

Comment: @SonnyOrdell No, the user knows not to accept the certificate. Unless you're an _extremely_ sophisticated user, or you're doing something weird, the rule is that if the browser gives you a warning, you are not secure and should not proceed. The certificate has done its job, which is to warn the user of the presence of the attacker.

Comment: Mike, there seems to be a misunderstanding. A certificate when implemented correctly, will not cause the browser to throw a warning. A warning will be caused from someone trying to MitM a connection. A cert without an IP in the AN field will do the same if the site is accessed by IP, invalidating any use the cert would have, as the user can't tell if is is trustworthy or not. An error will be thrown by *any* unrecognized cert, so the warning is not an argument for the cert having value.

Comment: @SonnyOrdell What I'm saying is that if you access a secure website with the wrong name, whether that's an IP address or an alternative hostname, then the site should not be considered secure _even if it happens to be secure on this occasion_. The use of the certificate is the same as it would be for a real attack; to tell you that you should not consider this session to be secure, _even if it is_.

Comment: I agree with your last comment, but I don't agree with your answer.